# Compress /sys and /proc

Tags: linux, zip

I want to put all files in /sys and /proc in zip files.

I tried this

```
 zip -r files.zip /sys
```

But get

```
 zip warning: name not matched: /sys/block/
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Those are virtual filesystems, not real files. You're bound to hit problems trying to do this.

Comment: I want to test script which collects data from /sys

Answer (score 0):

In linux `/proc` and `/sys` are special files. kind of virtual files for performing some task between user-space to kernel space communication.

They are just not regular files so you can not put them on zip file.